# I have two ArrayList A and B in a Jsp page and display values of A along with check if the B value are same

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Edit Plan</title>
</head>
<%! ArrayList<Edit_Pro> al;
ArrayList<String> st;
%>
<body>
<center>
<form action="Controller" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="edit" value="true">
<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Coverage</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
<%
al=(ArrayList<Edit_Pro>)request.getAttribute("pro");
st=(ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("cov");
for(Edit_Pro ep:al){
%>
<tr>
<th><input type="text" value="<%="INC"+ep.getId()%>" name="id" disabled="disabled"></th>
<th><input type="text" value="<%=ep.getName()%>" name="uname" ></th>
<th>
<% 
String pr[]=ep.getProduct().split(","); */ this bring a string. like :Accident,Dentist,beauty */
for(String s:st){
%> 
// I am confused here. 
<input type="checkbox" name="coverage" value="<%=s%>"  > <%=s%><br>

<%} %> 
</th>
<th><input type="text" name="status" value="<%=ep.getStatus() %>" disabled="disabled" ></th>
<th><input type="submit" value="Update">
</tr>
<%}%>
</table>
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code.
i Have one arrayList having List of Insurance and other for  Person ArrayList who can opt for one or more insurance. I want to display all insurance in checkbox with checked values for those insurance which that particular person have opted.
  [Expected Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY2AI.png)
 Thanks inAdvance

Comment: Please, post your code as editable code, not as an image.
Also specify what's your result and give an example of the expected result.

Comment: Done. Apology for not doing it in first place.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox may be enabled with attribute `checked="checked"`.

If you convert the product CSV to a List instead of an array you can use [List.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) (otherwise you would need another nested loop to iterate over `pr`).

So your JSP would look something like:

```
<% 
java.util.List<String> pr = java.util.Arrays.asList(ep.getProduct().split(",")); 
for(String s : st){
    %><input type="checkbox" name="coverage" value="<%=s%>" <%
    if(pr.contains(s)) {
        %>checked="checked"<%
    }
    %>><%=s%><br/><%    
<%} %>
```